# Valid XHTML error - <div> is not allowed in <a>

Tags: html, xhtml, w3c-validation

I am trying to validate my document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional. I have the following error:

> Line 73, Column 137: document type does not allow element "div" here;
> missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins",
> "del" start-tag

Which corresponds to this code:

```
<td><a href="download.php?f='.$file.'"><div class="download"></div></a></td>
```

Which I know is incorrect because a `<a>` can't contain a `<div>` tag. CSS code is:

```
.download { 
    width:30px;
    height:24px;
    background:url('../images/download.png') 0 0; 
}
    
.download:hover{ background:url('../images/download.png') 0 -24px;}
```

I am trying to show a link to download a file, the CSS puts the image and hover image, which are:

[image: download]

But inverting tag order like:

```
<td><div class="download"><a href="download.php?f='.$file.'"></a></div></td>
```

Shows the correct image and hover image, but not a clickable link. I don't know how to show the correct link.

Comment: I'm sure there's a reason, but why are you using XHTML not HTML5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link is not clickable because it is inline and is empty. This means it has zero width and height, so it is basically invisible. You should turn the `<a>` into a block element (so it will automatically adjust to the parent's width), and adjust it to its parent's (the `div`'s) fixed height:

```
.download a { display: block; height: 100%; }
```

Of course this is for the valid markup:

```
<td><div class="download"><a href="download.php?f='.$file.'"></a></div></td>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/aRNKV/) (with simple colored background, but it makes no difference)

Comment: An empty `a` element, though formally valid, is very bad for accessibility. Use a content image, with `img`, with a proper `alt` attribute and with a reasonable `title` attribute. Even then, it would be questionable; a link should normally have a descriptive link text.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela If you give the link a `title`, it could help a lot in itself, but I absolutely agree with what you have said.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just style the  tag like you do with the .download class and get rid of the div.  For instance, change it from

```
<td><div class="download"><a href="download.php?f='.$file.'"></a></div></td>
```

to

```
<td><a class="download" href="download.php?f='.$file.'"></a></td>
```

Comment: +1 This is a good solution either, if the `div` is not needed for something else.